# Format next month ('F')

Tags: php, html

How do i get the next month displayed?

```
$tz =  new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru');
$date = new DateTime('now', $tz);
$monthFull = $date->format('F');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Use `modify()`

```
$date = new DateTime('now', $tz);
$date->modify( 'next month' );
echo $date->format( 'F' ), "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the single line below to your existing code as shown.

```
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
```

### The code..

```
<?php
$tz =  new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru');
$date = new DateTime('now', $tz);
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));  //<------- Added here
echo $monthFull =  $date->format('F');  //"prints" March
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/100739)

Comment: Just be careful when adding month as you may end up two months later, as shown by Example #3 on the [PHP manual page on Datetime::add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php).

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran: Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
    $tz =  new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru');
    $date = new DateTime('now', $tz);
    $date->modify("+1 month");
    $monthFull = $date->format('F');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$timeStamp = strtotime('next month');
```